# Connection with hostapd stops working after 10 minutes

Tags: wifi

I have installed `hostapd` as package for Ubuntu 12.04. Everything is configured and works great for about 10 minutes; after that, packets start to get dropped and eventually I can't even connect. Restarting the hostapd service seems to fix everything for a further 10 minutes.

I am fairly fresh to Linux. What steps I can take to further debug this behaviour?

Comment: AskUbuntu might be a better place to ask this stuff. Laptop Wireless chipsets are not commonly used on servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try disabling WMM in your config with `wmm_enabled=0`.  There could be a powersave feature kicking in.  I had a similar issue and this solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Every precisely 10 minutes hostapd used to disconnect all my clients.
Using `wmm_enabled=0` did not help.
I changed the default parameter `wpa_group_rekey=600` to `wpa_group_rekey=1800` and the automatic disconnection happened only after 30 minutes.

```
# Time interval for rekeying GTK (broadcast/multicast encryption keys) in
# seconds. (dot11RSNAConfigGroupRekeyTime)
#wpa_group_rekey=600
```